# Create a conditional Interfaces based on value of the same interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Is it possible to create a conditional interface (IGeometry) in which the type of a property `shape` depends on the value that another property of the same interface, i.e. `geometryType`, takes on?

```
export enum GeometryType {
  CIRCLE = 4,
  POLYGON = 5,
  POINT = 6,
  ELLIPSE= 7
}

export interface ICircle {
  center: number;
  radius: number;
};

export interface IPolygon {
  lat: number;
  lon: number;
};

export interface IPoint {
  lat: number,
  lon: number
};

export interface IEllipse {
  yAxis: number;
  xAxis: number;
  angle: number;
};

export interface IGeometry {
  geometryType : GeometryType;
  shape:  ICircle | IPolygon | IPoint | IEllipse
}
```

Comment: TS doesn't have "conditional interfaces"; it has discriminated unions, which means `IGeometry` would have to be a type alias and not an interface.  You can either write out the type manually or compute it from a mapping of `GeometryType` to shape type, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N7VjPw).  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can achive this by defining a generic type `T` which represents the `geometryType` .

Here in the shape prop i am basically checking if passed `enum` prop is `CIRCLE , POLYGON , POINT or ELLIPSE` if so the `shape` type would be as given  otherwise it is of type `never`

```
export interface IGeometry<T extends GeometryType> {
  geometryType: T;
  shape: T extends GeometryType.CIRCLE
    ? ICircle
    : T extends GeometryType.POLYGON
    ? IPolygon
    : T extends GeometryType.POINT
    ? IPoint
    : T extends GeometryType.ELLIPSE
    ? IEllipse
    : never;
}
```

Now you can create some Objects here and pass in your desired type

```
const circle: IGeometry<GeometryType.CIRCLE> = {
  geometryType: GeometryType.CIRCLE,
  shape: {
    center: 0,
    radius: 5
  }
};

const polygon: IGeometry<GeometryType.POLYGON> = {
  geometryType: GeometryType.POLYGON,
  shape: {
    lat: 10.0000,
    lon: -10.0000
  }
}
```

Hope this helped .